# Error 403, "The caller does not have permission" when trying to impersonate Service Account in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, airflow, impersonation

I have this fairly easy Terraform configuration:

```json
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = { 
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.19.0"
    }   

    airflow = { 
      source = "DrFaust92/airflow"
      version = "~> 0.6.0"
    }   
  }
}

data "http" "client_id" {
  url = var.cloud_composer.airflow_uri
}

resource "google_service_account" "impersonated-gsa" {
  account_id = "impersonated"
}

data "google_service_account_access_token" "impersonated" {
  target_service_account = google_service_account.impersonated-gsa.email
  delegates              = []
  scopes                 = ["userinfo-email", "cloud-platform"]
  lifetime               = "300s"
}

provider "google" {
  alias        = "impersonated"
  access_token = data.google_service_account_access_token.impersonated.access_token
}

data "google_service_account_id_token" "oidc" {
  provider               = google.impersonated
  target_service_account = google_service_account.impersonated-gsa.email
  delegates              = []
  include_email          = true
  target_audience        = regex("[A-Za-z0-9-]*\\.apps\\.googleusercontent\\.com", data.http.client_id.body)
}

provider "airflow" {
  base_endpoint = data.http.client_id.url
  oauth2_token = data.google_service_account_id_token.oidc.id_token
}
```

The configuration is mostly directly copied from the documentation of [Terraform Airflow provider](https://github.com/DrFaust92/terraform-provider-airflow/blob/master/docs/index.md#google-composer-example).

When I try to run Terraform on it, say for example `terraform plan`, I get this 403 error:

```
╷
│ Error: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden
│ 
│   with module.airflow.data.google_service_account_access_token.impersonated,
│   on modules/airflow/providers.tf line 23, in data "google_service_account_access_token" "impersonated":
│   23: data "google_service_account_access_token" "impersonated" {
│ 
╵
```

I am running Terraform in my local terminal, being authenticated with my `gcloud` user as stated in [Terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#primary-authentication). My user has actual **Owner** role in GCP, which should require no more permissions to do this job, as far as I know. Anyway, I added myself the `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` role as well, which seems needed to perform this operation, but didn't help and the error is the same.

At this point, I have no idea what could I be doing wrong, or even if the Terraform configuration itself is correct.

Can someone give any advice or suggestion? Thanks.

**Edit** to add more details because I can't put an entire answer to John Hanley comment:

Right,

1. I haven't see `userinfo-email` in any doc. Actually [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/service_account_access_token#example-usage), [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/service_account_id_token#example-usage---service-account-impersonation) and [here](https://github.com/DrFaust92/terraform-provider-airflow/blob/master/docs/index.md#google-composer-example) is always `userinfo-email`. Anyway, I changed to `userinfo.email`. This didn't affect the results.
2. I checked that to exhaustion, and indeed my user account, the only one I had configured to run Terraform, is an Owner. There is no chance I am running Terraform with any other non-Owner user.
3. Okay, so to triple check now I manually created a Service Account in GCP dashboard, assigned it Owner role, also assigned it Service Account Token Creator role. Then I configured my local to run Terraform with that, and the error is exactly the same.

So, the mistake must be in the TF configuration.

Comment: Are you sure that you use your user credential to run terraform? If so, how did you validate that?

Comment: I'm sure I run Terraform with my user credentials because I haven't configured Terraform to run otherwise, and when I run `gcloud auth list` I see that my GCP user is selected.

Answer (score 3):

1. The scope **userinfo-email** is invalid. It should be **userinfo.email**.
2. You state that you are using an account with the **Owner** role. However, the error message indicates that you are not using that identity with Terraform.
3. Using a user identity can result in errors (API quotas). You should be using a service account. I recommend allocating a service account, assigning it the required roles, and initializing the Terraform provider with the service account.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal might be configured with Environment Variables, which I had the same issue with.
`GOOGLE_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` env was configured in my case, which caused the issue.